# Move object on Canvas using textbox input

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, addeventlistener

I've got a canvas on which I can add layers, these layers I can move, select, rotate, resize etc. Below the canvas I display the properties of the layer (x, y, width, height).

What I am trying to do is when I change the values in the textboxes containing the x and y coördinates the layer should be repositioned to the coördinates I typed in.

I've tried several things but everything seems to mess up the canvas, I am using this to move the layer on `mousemove` now:

```
else if (layerState == MOVING && mouseDown) {
    selectedLayer.offsetX += e.pageX - canvasOffsetX - mousePrevX;
    selectedLayer.offsetY += e.pageY - canvasOffsetY - mousePrevY;

    drawMarker(selectedLayer);
}
```

And I use this to get the x and y of the layer:

```
document.getElementById('x').value = Math.round(layer.offsetX*100)/100;
document.getElementById('y').value = Math.round(layer.offsetY*100)/100;
```

A working example of my canvas and the code can be found here:

http://cdpn.io/fjzcv

I've also tried to work with these examples but couldn't get any of them to work:

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001654/ch03.html#text_arranger_version_2.0
http://fabricjs.com/controls/

I have tried setting an eventListener on the texboxes but when I do this the canvas will dissapear.

If anyone knows how to do this it would be great!

**EDIT:**

I found out a way to change the coördinates onchange with the textbox but now I can just change them to a set number instead of taking the value I filled in the textbox:

```
document.getElementById('x').onchange=function(){selectedLayer.offsetX = 100;
drawMarker(selectedLayer);
};

document.getElementById('y').onchange=function(){selectedLayer.offsetY = 100;
drawMarker(selectedLayer);
};
```

Anyone knows how to get it to move to the filled in coördinate?

Answer (score 0):

I tried editing the HTML on the code pen and I think this should work.

Firstly add an event listener to your text boxes, where you've got the canvas ones.

```
document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('onchange',updatePos,false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveEvent, false);
....
```

Then create a similar function to your `mouseMoveEvent(e)` to change the selected layer values

```
function updatePos(e) {
    var temp = document.getElementById('x').value;
    selectedLayer.offsetX = canvas.offsetX + temp;
    drawMarker(selectedLayer);
}
```

Obviously you may need to add in validation or change this to suit your code, but it should get the object moving around.

Comment: Thnx for the response but adding an event listener to the text boxes will cause the canvas to fail (dissapear/turn black?). If you did get this to work do you mind editing the codepen and showing it?

Comment: Have you been able to get it to work in the codepen?

Comment: Sorry no I haven't had a chance. Putting in an Event handler shouldn't effect the canvas. It would be worth checking what error is being thrown. Use the developer tools in chrome, or Firebug in FireFox. Afraid I won't have a chance to look over the next few days, but I will when I can.

Comment: I did find another way to get this to work but it does have some flaws in it which you can read in [this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672469/reposition-element-on-html5-canvas-when-changing-x-and-y-in-textbox) so I don't know if you still wanna try getting your way to work but if you do get it to work it would be great!